# How to call printf from x86/32 GNU assembler?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gnu-assembler, binutils

I have written a small x86/32 assembler program that calls `printf` and gets compiled with `gcc -m32 x.s`:

```
     .data
format:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    mov     $56, %eax
    push    %eax
    call    get_pc_eax
    add     $format - ., %eax
    push    %eax
    # call  printf@PLT
    call    get_pc_eax
    add     $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %eax
    mov     printf@GOT(%eax), %eax
    call    *%eax
    add     $8, %esp
    xor     %eax, %eax
    ret
get_pc_eax:
    mov     (%esp), %eax
    ret
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

If I enable the commented-out line `call printf@PLT` instead of the 4 lines after it (like it is now), then nothing happens on execution. I have some questions:

- Do I have to initialize the PLT before calling into it?
- Is this the recommended way to call a function in position independent code? It feels somewhat clumsy.
- I have searched for several hours and could not find a tutorial for i386 assembler on Linux using gas/gcc that also explains calling into libc and position independent code. I would be grateful if anyone could post a link.

**UPDATE:**
After some extended discussion I came up with this code for `main`:

```
 1  push    %ebx
 2  mov     $56, %ebx
 3  push    %ebx
 4  call    get_pc_ebx
 5  add     $format - ., %ebx
 6  push    %ebx
 7  call    get_pc_ebx
 8  add     $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %ebx
 9  xor     %eax, %eax
10  call    printf@PLT
11  add     $8, %esp
12  pop     %ebx
13  xor     %eax, %eax
14  ret
```

This code works. If I comment out the setup of `%ebx` in lines 7 and 8 the code crashes. From this I figure `%ebx` needs to point to the global offset table.

Can anyone link a tutorial/article/source that explains this mechanism?

Comment: Have you run `gcc -S -fPIC -fverbose-asm -Os` on a simple Hello World C program, to see what approach the compiler uses?

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b5frqvE6P

Comment: I actually have, but the results did not really enlighten me. Thus the question. Besides, I specifically search for 32 bit answers where the neat PC relative `%rip` versions of commands do not exist.

Comment: The `-m32` flag works on godbolt, I have linked to an example including that.

Comment: Oh yes, I know. I use this site quite a bit. But the exact mechanism why my examples with `printf@PLT` do not work still escapes me :(

Comment: The `-m32` output from godbolt does use `printf@PLT`, after some setup.  Is that setup not what you're looking for?

Comment: My local example is like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fcr7d4vnr). I specifically cannot see how the assembly for `printf@PLT` works, especially lines 4, 6, 12 and 13 elude me (anything to do with %ecx).

Comment: The use of `ecx` is unnecessary nonsense apparently, clang omits it.  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f433qY36d

Comment: I am still unsure, but is it that `%ebx` needs to point to the GOT for the code at `printf@PLT` to resolve the correct address? It looks like it. Where is that documented? Information on these things is what I am searching for!

Comment: I believe that `ebx`, which is a copy of the instruction pointer, is only being used to find the string literal

Comment: But [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KchqfWPsG) there's no string literal and `ebx` is still setup so you may be correct.

Comment: Nope, it seems essential to initialize it to the address of the GOT. I will update my question.

Comment: https://maskray.me/blog/2021-09-19-all-about-procedure-linkage-table

Comment: Ok this mentions that %ebx needs to point to the base of the GOT. This whole scheme for x86/32 is pretty contrived.